# Count the number of items in my array list

Tags: java

I want to count the number of itemids in my array, can i get an example of how i would go about adding this to my code. code below;

```
if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
    Set set = value.keySet();
    Object[] key = set.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(key);

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        ArrayList list = (ArrayList) value.get((String) key[i]);

        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator iter = list.iterator();
            double itemValue = 0;
            String itemId = "";

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Propertyunbuf p = (Propertyunbuf) iter.next();
                if (p != null) {
                    itemValue = itemValue + p.getItemValue().doubleValue();
                    itemId = p.getItemId();
                }

                buf2.append(NL);
                buf2.append("                  " + itemId);

            }

            double amount = itemValue;
            totalAmount += amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the question meshes well with the sample code. Are you looking for the number of 'distinct' itemIds or similar?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The number of `itemId`s in your list will be the same as the number of elements in your list:

```
int itemCount = list.size();
```

However, if you're looking to count the number of unique itemIds (per @pst) then you should use a set to keep track of them.

```
Set<String> itemIds = new HashSet<String>();

//...
itemId = p.getItemId();
itemIds.add(itemId);

//... later ...
int uniqueItemIdCount = itemIds.size();
```

Answer (score 15):

You want to count the number of itemids in your array. Simply use:

```
int counter=list.size();
```

Less code increases efficiency. Do not re-invent the wheel...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of elements in the list by calling `list.size()`, however some of the elements may be duplicates or `null` (if your list implementation allows `null`).

If you want the number of unique items and your items implement `equals` and `hashCode` correctly you can put them all in a set and call `size` on that, like this:

```
new HashSet<>(list).size()
```

If you want the number of items with a distinct `itemId` you can do this:

```
list.stream().map(i -> i.itemId).distinct().count()
```

Assuming that the type of `itemId` correctly implements `equals` and `hashCode` (which `String` in the question does, unless you want to do something like ignore case, in which case you could do `map(i -> i.itemId.toLowerCase())`).

You may need to handle `null` elements by either filtering them before the call to `map`: `filter(Objects::nonNull)` or by providing a default itemId for them in the `map` call: `map(i -> i == null ? null : i.itemId)`.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of your loop create an int:

```
int numberOfItemIds = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
```

Then in the loop, increment it:

```
itemId = p.getItemId();
numberOfItemIds++;
```

Comment: Damn. I think Mark Peters posted a better solution right before I did.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense to try to count every step through a loop when you already have the length of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 stream API:

```
 String[] keys = new String[0];

// A map for keys and their count
Map<String, Long> keyCountMap = Arrays.stream(keys).
collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
int uniqueItemIdCount= keyCountMap.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would add to Mark Peters solution is that you don't need to iterate over the ArrayList - you should be able to use the addAll(Collection) method on the Set.  You only need to iterate over the entire list to do the summations.

Comment: The list contains `Propertyunbuf` objects while the desired set contains Strings.  You can't use addAll from one to the other...you would need something like Google Collection's transform to do that.

Comment: Good point.  Though I believe if the equals() method of the Propertyunbuf object used the itemId you could declare your set as a collection of Propertyunbuf and get the same net result.  Still I like your approach better - I just like to explore options and alternatives :)